# It appears that my question is being displayed with missing content. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I asked a question on Music Stack Exchange this morning.  I returned to the question and saw that the question doesn't display correctly when I browse to it, but when I click [Edit], it does display correctly in the editor.

I am attaching screenshots to show the errant behavior.  Where the red circle is drawn, it should show `B5: T-23----`

[image]

Comment: It's jtab trying to render what you are doing. Don't use the code blocks for things like that only for jtab and abcjs. You can use the <pre></pre> tags to give a similar effect.